# Ruby, post and redirect

Tags: ruby, post, redirect, sinatra

I have situation like this:

- user submits form with `action='/pay'`
- in '/pay' I have to add some additional parameters and send post request to `www.paymentprovider.com/new_payment`

The problem is that I want to post and redirect (at the same time) user to this new website `www.paymentprovider.com/new_payment`. Currently I am using

```
Net::HTTP.post_form
```

Do you know any ways to achieve this?

Comment: are you using cgi to run the ruby scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do a post and redirect without breaking the internet. :)

If you want to use this workflow, you will need to proxy the request.

As an example:

1. User submits to /pay
2. You grab those paramaters and make a request to /new_payment
3. You can grab the results from /new_payment and send them back to the request in /pay

Since this is all happening locally, the option above would seem to be a waste. If /pay is simply missing some parameters and info could you simply supply them in your view? This way you could have both /pay and /new_payment postback to the same location and use two separate views to handle the initial get request.